# не загружается модуль yatank_OnlineRep

Tags: яндекс-танк

Как я понял старый плагин онлайн-графиков канул в лету (http://clubs.ya.ru/yandex-tank/replies.xml?item_no=510) и ему на смену пришел yatank-online. Пробую им воспользоваться и на старте Танка получаю ошибки следующего рода:

```
14:53:00 INFO: Loading configs...
14:53:00 INFO: Loading plugins...
14:53:00 INFO: Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/yandex-tank/Tank/ConsoleWorker.py", line 183, in configure
    self.core.load_plugins()
  File "/usr/lib/yandex-tank/tankcore.py", line 233, in load_plugins
    instance = self.__load_plugin(plugin_name, plugin_path)
  File "/usr/lib/yandex-tank/tankcore.py", line 257, in __load_plugin
    exec ("import " + classname)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named yatank_OnlineRep

14:53:00 ERROR: No module named yatank_OnlineRep
14:53:00 ERROR: Exception: No module named yatank_OnlineRep
```

Сам модуль ставился пипом и по-умолчанию лег в */usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yatank_OnlineReport/* в то время как основные плагины лежат в */usr/lib/yandex-tank/Tank/Plugins/*. По каким путям, кроме своего родного дира, Танк еще ищет и как его завернуть в нужное место?

- Ubuntu 1404
- Tank 1.6.8 (ppa installed)
- yatank-online 0.0.5 (pip installed)

Comment: У нас тут есть специалист по [tag:yandex-tank] ([r2d2](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195593/r2d2)), но он что-то долго не показывался.

Comment: @VladD: Direvius тоже специалист )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас старый танк, текущая версия 1.7.28. Начиная с ветки 1.7 изменился способ импортирования плагинов (теперь это стандартный питонячий импорт). Поставьте 1.7.28 -- должно заработать.

**UPD**: начиная с ветки танка 1.8 мы потеряли совместимость с этим плагином. Старый код сохранен [тут](https://github.com/yandex-load/yatank-online/tree/1.7_branch), эта же версия сейчас в PyPI. Совместимость с новой версией in progress, работа идет в мастере репозитория.

Вместо плагина онлайн отчета советую использовать сервис [Overload](https://overload.yandex.net/mainpage/guide#install). Это бесплатно и там больше возможностей.

Если все-таки хочется плагин, то ставить так:

`pip install https://api.github.com/repos/yandex-load/yatank-online/tarball/master`

Comment: Благодарю, перелил все с нуля, помогло. Правильно ли я понимаю, что теперь ставиться нужно через ман на гитхабе "Install from PyPI", нежели на readthedocs?

Comment: А вы давно ставили танк из deb пакетов? По идее, для trusty на ланчпаде есть собранный  yandex-tank_1.7.28_all.deb

Comment: А как у вас вообще получилось 1.6.8 поставить? Это старый пакет, он называется yandex-load-tank-base (поудалял теперь его из репозитория, чтобы не смущать). А новый называется yandex-tank и в readthedocs [написанно](http://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html), что ставить надо его. Вы где-то еще нашли про yandex-load-tank-base?

Comment: Разливал ферму через ансиблю, перед установкой проверил актуальность плэйбука (писал его относительно давно), т.е. залез в ppa посмотреть что изменилось, на месте ли пакеты, и похоже он меня таки и смутил. В инсталлгайде не увидел ничего нового (угу, конечно), оказалось глаз замылился. Извиняюсь за внесенную смуту, зато репорты теперь есть ))) Всем спасибо.