# Yandex.Tank не резолвит модуль yatank-online

Tags: python, яндекс-танк

Установил плагин как [на странице репозитория](https://github.com/yandex-load/yatank-online). Сам танк работает нормально. С плагином нет. Ошибка `ImportError: No module named Report`

Проверил предыдущие вопросы, а именно [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482341/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-yatank-onlinerep). Не помогло и не подходит. У меня версия 1.8.35.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так? Симпотмы те же, что и автора другого вопроса. Основные плагины лежат внутри самого пакета танка, а этот репорт выкинут наружу, и естественно танк не знает как его подхватить. Может какие другие диррективы нужны для самого танка или при устнановке?

Сам файл конфигурации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Update 1**

После создания символьной ссылки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ссыль, что Вы указали вроде как для 1.7_ версии? А Вы пробовали просто в интерпретаторе импортировать `import yandextank.plugins.Report`

Comment: @IgorSergeevich, да, пробовал. Ни в интерпретаторе ни в файловой системе ее нету. Я зашел и смотрел уже в папке пакетов питона. Она лежит сразу в dist-packages, a танк пробуте искать в своей внутренней plugins.

Comment: @IgorSergeevich, и по поводу ссылки. Там же первой строчкой вроде вот, что написано. "This doc is for new version of a plugin (currently work-in-progress). The old one (code and doc) is here: ", Так, что инсталл, должен быть правильным. Версия самого плагина 0.0.9, судя по pip.

Comment: попробуйте символьную ссылку сделать `ln -s /from /to`

Comment: @IgorSergeevich, Добавил скриншот после создания символьной ссылки. Пробую отключить этот мониторинг плагин, но на самом деле, вообще не понимаю, каким он здесь боком.

Comment: К сожалению это может быть не единственной проблемой, похоже что-то пошло не так, нет необходимых зависимостей, попробуйте все же устранить первую ошибку

Comment: @IgorSergeevich, В том и проблема. Делал все по инструкции и никаких ошибок. Довольно сложно входить в любые технологии, если стандартные вещи сразу же начинаются с тяжелых ошибок. Извиняюсь с тавтологию.

Comment: Если ещё есть возможность, пожалуйста, вставьте весь текст с картинок прямо в вопрос. Для форматирования нажмите в редакторе кнопку `{}` или комбинацию клавиш Ctrl+K

Answer (score 1):

Плагин версии 0.0.9 совместим только со старой (1.7) версией танка. Плагин для новой версии танка сейчас в состоянии "ну как-то работает". Вместо него пока что советую использовать сервис [overload.yandex.net](http://overload.yandex.net/mainpage/guide#install) – это бесплатно и возможностей больше.

Если хотите все-таки его поставить, то версия в репозитории – 1.8.1. Она не залита в PyPI, ее нужно ставить прямо из репозитория:

`pip install https://api.github.com/repos/yandex-load/yatank-online/tarball/master`

Comment: Я пока так и решил воспользоваться overload. Правда меня смущает этот глобальный подход к отображению тестов. Все же, не все заказчики могут согласиться данными тестов отображаемых всем. По этой причине очень жду стабильной версии локального отрисовщика. Можно было и с графитом поморочится, но, пока некоторое время можно и так потестировать.